# if an option is selected in a select list, how to disable the option with the same value in another select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 2 select inputs where if i select from first one and second one have same values disable from second input select just that option to block user to select 2 same values.
here is my html:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#tip_rola1').change(function(){
        var tip_rola1 = $(this).val();

      $('#tip_rola2').change(function(){
        var tip_rola2 = $(this).val();
        var n1 = tip_rola1;
        if(tip_rola1 === tip_rola2) {
          alert(tip_rola2);
         
        }

      })
        

      })

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>select 1</span>
<select class="form-control show_data1" id="tip_rola1" name="tip_rola2">
   <option selected=""> Select</option>
   <option value="8"> 70</option>
   <option value="9"> 76</option>
   <option value="10"> 80</option>
   <option value="11"> 84</option>
   <option value="12"> 35</option>
   <option value="13"> 38</option>
   <option value="14"> 40</option>
   <option value="15"> 42</option>
</select>
<span>select 2</span>
<select class="form-control show_data2" id="tip_rola2" name="tip_rola2">
   <option selected=""> Select</option>
   <option value="8"> 70</option>
   <option value="9"> 76</option>
   <option value="10"> 80</option>
   <option value="11"> 84</option>
   <option value="12"> 35</option>
   <option value="13"> 38</option>
   <option value="14"> 40</option>
   <option value="15"> 42</option>
</select>
```

If select 1 on change have same values with select 2 on select 2 i want to disable that option which was selected on first select option.

Update for few ppl who think i didnt try anything and i just asking.

Comment: So now the problem was title or the real question?don`t be mean i am trying to learn.

Comment: There is **no** question here. You just described the desired behavior.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how i can detect when 2 select inputs have same option selected...

Answer (score 1):

### Answer:

- `HTMLSelectElement` already contains an `HTMLCollection` of option
  elements for each box. This is accessible through
  `HTMLSelectElement.options`. You don't need to make a separate query
  to get these elements.
- **Keep in mind** that `options` returns an `HTMLCollection` and *not* an Array, it doesn't come with Array methods like `forEach`, but it
  is still iterable by utilizing a `for` loop.
- `HTMLSelectElement` also has a `selectedIndex` property that denotes
  which `option` has been selected. This allows us to get the currently
  selected option like so: `HTMLSelectElement.options[
  HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex ]`.

---

Your `change` event listener can be adjusted as follows to get the desired effect:

```
// Get selected value of first Select
  const selected = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;

// Adjust second Select options 
  for (let opt of s2.options) {
    opt.disabled = opt.value === selected;
  }
```

### Example:

```js
let [s, s2] = document.querySelectorAll("select");

s.addEventListener("change", function() {
  const selected = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
  for (let opt of s2.options) {
    opt.disabled = opt.value === selected;
  }
});
```

```html
<span>select 1</span>
<select class="form-control show_data1" id="tip_rola1" name="tip_rola2">
  <option selected=""> Select</option>
  <option value="8"> 70</option>
  <option value="9"> 76</option>
  <option value="10"> 80</option>
  <option value="11"> 84</option>
  <option value="12"> 35</option>
  <option value="13"> 38</option>
  <option value="14"> 40</option>
  <option value="15"> 42</option>
</select>
<span>select 2</span>
<select class="form-control show_data2" id="tip_rola2" name="tip_rola2">
  <option selected=""> Select</option>
  <option value="8"> 70</option>
  <option value="9"> 76</option>
  <option value="10"> 80</option>
  <option value="11"> 84</option>
  <option value="12"> 35</option>
  <option value="13"> 38</option>
  <option value="14"> 40</option>
  <option value="15"> 42</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Very good catches in this answer! To add to it, depending on the targeted ecma script version / browser compatibility, you can use `Array.from()` or the spread operator `[...nodeListOrHtmlCollection]` to convert an HTMLCollection or a NodeList into an array and make use of its methods.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show any effort of your own, but given that you're new-ish and the solution is quite simple, here's a snippet demonstrating the desired behaviour. Whenever one of the selects changes, loop over the options in the other one and set their `disabled` attributes, either to `true` if it has the same value as selected in the changed select, otherwise to `false`.

By the way, your first select with `id="tip_rola1"` should also have the `name` attribute set to `"tip_rola1"` instead of `"tip_rola2"`.

```js
function selectChangehandler(event) {
  let thisSelect = event.target;
  let otherSelect = document.getElementById(`tip_rola${thisSelect.id === 'tip_rola1' ? 2 : 1}`);
  otherSelect.querySelectorAll('option').forEach(function(option) {
    option.disabled = option.value === thisSelect.value;
  });
}

document.getElementById('tip_rola1').addEventListener('change', selectChangehandler);
document.getElementById('tip_rola2').addEventListener('change', selectChangehandler);
```

```html
<span>select 1</span>
<select class="form-control show_data1" id="tip_rola1" name="tip_rola1">
   <option selected=""> Select</option>
   <option value="8"> 70</option>
   <option value="9"> 76</option>
   <option value="10"> 80</option>
   <option value="11"> 84</option>
   <option value="12"> 35</option>
   <option value="13"> 38</option>
   <option value="14"> 40</option>
   <option value="15"> 42</option>
</select>
<span>select 2</span>
<select class="form-control show_data2" id="tip_rola2" name="tip_rola2">
   <option selected=""> Select</option>
   <option value="8"> 70</option>
   <option value="9"> 76</option>
   <option value="10"> 80</option>
   <option value="11"> 84</option>
   <option value="12"> 35</option>
   <option value="13"> 38</option>
   <option value="14"> 40</option>
   <option value="15"> 42</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Edward we're not all living in your country. Some might have a nice night, evening, morning... Please try to ask questions by also pointing at what was your issue with the current code.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could add a `function` and send the `event` as an argument like so:

```js
const validate = event => {       

    const id = event.target.id;      
    const dropdowns = ['tip_rola1','tip_rola2'];
    const secondDropdownId = dropdowns.filter(x => x !== id)[0];
    
    const secondDropdown = document.getElementById(secondDropdownId); 
    const dropdownSelected = document.getElementById(id);    
    
    if(event.target.value === secondDropdown.value){
      secondDropdown.setAttribute('disabled','');
      dropdownSelected.setAttribute('disabled', '');     
    }
    else {      
      dropdownSelected.removeAttribute('disabled'); 
      secondDropdown.removeAttribute('disabled'); 
    }    
}
```

```html
<span>select 1</span>
<select id="tip_rola1" onchange="validate(event)">
   <option selected=""> Select</option>
   <option value="8"> 70</option>
   <option value="9"> 76</option>
   <option value="10"> 80</option>
   <option value="11"> 84</option>
   <option value="12"> 35</option>
   <option value="13"> 38</option>
   <option value="14"> 40</option>
   <option value="15"> 42</option>
</select>
<span>select 2</span>
<select id="tip_rola2" onchange="validate(event)">
   <option selected=""> Select</option>
   <option value="8"> 70</option>
   <option value="9"> 76</option>
   <option value="10"> 80</option>
   <option value="11"> 84</option>
   <option value="12"> 35</option>
   <option value="13"> 38</option>
   <option value="14"> 40</option>
   <option value="15"> 42</option>
</select>
```